# youtube api search respond unexpected data

Tags: youtube-api

We are using youtube API for searching our own video files, and the search result responds with data that has no information about the query search, for example:

search: **cultura**
result: some videos has not **cultura** in the title, description or tags

API call for video list:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=KEY&channelId=CHANNELID&part=snippet&order=date&q=cultura&maxResults=50

Response:

```
  "items" => array:50 [▼
    0 => array:4 [▼
...
      "snippet" => array:8 [▼
...
        "title" => "Primavera"
        "description" => "Arroyo y cascada del rio Castaños en la cara norte del Eretza ([eitb.com][g1] [tiempo-naturaleza] [ bizkaia] [ galdames] [alberto-zorrilla] [1755] [tiemponaturaleza] )
...
```

API call for video information:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=KEY&channelId=CHANNELID&part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&id=ID

```
...
        "title": "Primavera",
        "description": "Arroyo y cascada del rio Castaños en la cara norte del Eretza ([eitb.com][g1] [tiempo-naturaleza] [ bizkaia] [ galdames] [alberto-zorrilla] [1755]  [tiemponaturaleza] )",
...
        "tags": [
          "category2:tiemponaturaleza",
          "category:tiempo-naturaleza",
          "city:galdames",
          "domain:eitb.com",
          "id_user:1755",
          "province:bizkaia",
          "type:g1",
          "username:alberto-zorrilla"
        ],
        "categoryId": "22",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "localized": {
          "title": "Primavera",
          "description": "Arroyo y cascada del rio Castaños en la cara norte del Eretza ([eitb.com][g1] [tiempo-naturaleza] [ bizkaia] [ galdames] [alberto-zorrilla] [1755]  [tiemponaturaleza] )"
        }
      }
```

...
,

Some help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Unfortunately, Google does not specify (neither document) the actual meaning of the results provided by the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint. The very same is true for its search functionality accessible on YouTube's website.

Comment: The default search is by relevance, not keyword match. If the algorithm thinks the content is close, it is included in the results.

Comment: I supposed that @johnh10, finally I created a function to filter the youtube search results